# Assert RDD is not sorted

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, scalatest

I have a method called `split` that accepts an RDD[T] and a splitSize and returns an Array[RDD[T]].

Now, one of the test cases I write for it should verify that this function also randomly shuffles the RDD.

So I create a sorted RDD, and then see the results:

```
  it should "randomize shuffle" in {
    val inputRDD = sc.parallelize((0 until 16))
    val result = RDDUtils.split(inputRDD, 2)

    result.foreach(rdd => {
      rdd.collect.foreach(println)
    })

    // Asset result is not sorted
  }
```

If the results are:

0
1
2
3
..
15

Then it's not working as expected.

A good result can be something like:

11
3
9
14
...
1
6

How can I assert the output Array[RDD[T]]] is not sorted?

Comment: So you want random order withing a partition or within Array of partitions?

Comment: @SamirVyas I want to make sure that subsequent numbers have a good chance to be in different partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```scala
val resultOrder = result.sortBy(....)
assert(!resultOrder.sameElements(result))
```

or

```scala
val resultOrder = result.sortBy(....)
assert(!resultOrder.toList == result.toList)
```

It's important to note that the key is to know how to sort the Array. For an Integer data type it would be easy, but for a complex data type you could need an **implicit Ordering** for your data type. e.g:

```scala
implicit val ordering: Ordering[T] =
    Ordering.fromLessThan[T]((sa: T, sb: T) => sa < sb)

// OR

implicit val ordering: Ordering[MyClass] =
    Ordering.fromLessThan[MyClass]((sa: MyClass, sb: MyClass) => sa.field1 < sb.field1)
```

The exact code would depend of your data type.

As a full example of this

```scala
package tests

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SortArrayRDD {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("SortArrayRDD")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id","SortArrayRDD") // To silence Metrics warning
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    try {

      Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

      val arrRDD: Array[RDD[Int]] = Array(sc.parallelize(List(2,3)),sc.parallelize(List(10,11)),sc.parallelize(List(6,7)),sc.parallelize(List(8,9)),
        sc.parallelize(List(4,5)),sc.parallelize(List(0,1)),sc.parallelize(List(12,13)),sc.parallelize(List(14,15)))
      val aux = arrRDD

      implicit val ordering: Ordering[RDD[Int]] = Ordering.fromLessThan[RDD[Int]]((sa: RDD[Int], sb: RDD[Int]) => sa.sum() < sb.sum())

      aux.sorted.foreach(rdd => println(rdd.collect().mkString(",")))

      val resultOrder = aux.sorted

      assert(!resultOrder.sameElements(arrRDD))
      println("It's unordered")
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need the result to be unordered!

Comment: I need to assert that the result is unordered

Comment: Hi @Alon, you mean that you want to check if result is ordered or not, don't you? because if not I misunderstood the question and I will remove my answer.

Comment: The code you posted asserts that the result is ordered, if it's not - the test fails. I want the opposite: I need to assert that the result is unordered, if it's ordered - then the test should fail.

Comment: Each element of the result is an RDD[T]. This is why it's complicated. Could you please provide me a complete code that compiles and works? Assuming the function splits the data successfully into RDD of two elements, the result should be anything but this: Array [RDD[0,1],RDD[2,3],RDD[4,5],RDD[6,7],RDD[8,9],RDD[10,11],[RDD[12,13],[RDD[14,15]]

Comment: Hi @Alon, sorry if the example wasn't clear,  I edited my post again. I hope it can help you or give some clues. Regards.